# givens rotation from right side

Tags: linear-algebra

:)

I have this matrix:

B =  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.626 & 2.56 & 2.15 & \\
    0.835 & 6.66 & 5.16 & \\
    0 & 0 & -1.65 & 
  \end{bmatrix}

I was wondering how to find a givens matrix such that I could apply it from the right side of the matrix and eliminate B[2][1] (0.835).

B*g = \begin{bmatrix}
    * & * & * & \\
    0 & * & * & \\
    0 & 0 & * & 
  \end{bmatrix}
Best regards,
rox

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361442/380384

> ```
>     | a  b  tx |
> A = | c  d  ty |
>     | 0  0  1  |
> ```
>
> which transforms the coordinates [x,y,1] into:
>
> ```
> [x',y',1] = A * [x,y,1]
> ```
>
> Thus set the traslation into `[dx,dy]=[tx,ty]`
>
> The scale is `sx=sqrt(a^2+b^2)` and `sy=sqrt(c^2+d^2)`
>
> The rotation angle is `t=atan(c/d)` or `t=atan(-b/a)` as also they should be the same.

The inverse matrix is $$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{a d-b c} \begin{bmatrix} 
d & -b & b t_y-d t_x \\
-c & a & c t_x-a t_y \\
0 & 0 & a d - b c \end{bmatrix} $$

Or you can try

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b & t_x \\ c & d & t_y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{c}{d} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a-\frac{b c}{d} & b & t_x \\ 0 & d & t_y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Thank you ja72. Your answer is about givens rotation or is another method?

Comment: yes. Right hand rule planar rotation, with $a=d=\cos \theta$ and $b=-c=-\sin\theta$

Comment: Is this matrix orthogonal?

Comment: No. only the first 2×2 elements are orthonomal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with left-applied Givens rotations, you can take the transpose of your desired equation an end up in more familiar territory, where your goal becomes creating a lower-triangular matrix with a left-applied Givens rotation.

$$(\begin{bmatrix} c & -s & 0 \\ s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.626 & 0.835 & 0 \\ 2.56 & 6.66 & 0 \\ 2.15 & 5.16 & −1.65\end{bmatrix})^T$$

Lets undo this transposition and look at how this affects the desired Givens matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0.626 & 0.835 & 0 \\ 2.56 & 6.66 & 0 \\ 2.15 & 5.16 & −1.65\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} c & -s & 0 \\ s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0.626 & 2.56 & 2.15 \\ 0.835 & 6.66 & 5.16 \\ 0 & 0 & −1.65\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} c & s & 0 \\ -s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

So finding the appropriate values for a right-multiplied givens upon some matrix $M$ is very clearly the transpose of finding the appropriate values for a left-multiplied givens upon $M^T$.

But for a more thorough explanation of Givens matrices in general:

Left-applied Givens rotations only affect the rows that **c** and **s** apply to, so lets reduce our visuals to those rows, and the one column we want to zero.

$$\begin{bmatrix} c & -s \\ s & c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.835 \\ 6.66 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ r\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that the sign of s is related to which component gets zeroed out.
Given **a = 0.835** and **b = 6.66**
We want to find **c** & **s** such that:

$$c*a - s*b = 0$$ $$s*a + c*b = r$$

With **r** being the magnitude of our current vector of focus.
The easy solution would be to say:

$$c = b/r$$ $$s = a/r$$

The first equation trivially reduces to zero.  Our second equation becomes:

$$\frac{a^2}r + \frac{b^2}r = r$$
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}r = r$$
$$r^2/r = r$$

So for $\begin{bmatrix}0.835 \\ 6.66 \end{bmatrix}$, $r = \sqrt{0.835^2 + 6.66^2} = 6.71214$

In this instance, $c = \frac{6.66}{6.71214}$ and $s = \frac{0.835}{6.71214}$

Once $c$ and $s$ are known, constructing the desired Givens matrix becomes trivial.